# TypeError: a is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux

My app was working fine until I decided to move the project to a new ubuntu system,
when I tried to run the program it throws an error saying:

```
TypeError: a is not a function
 throw new Error('Expected the enhancer to be a function.')
```

I tried looking at my redux store settings my found nothing.
Here's my code:

```
import { compose, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';

import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import persistedReducer from './reducers/index';

const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  compose(
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
  ),
);
const persistor = persistStore(store);
export { store, persistor };
```

Comment: how you tell exactly that error comes from the Redux store?

Comment: throw new Error('Expected the enhancer to be a function.');
  77 |   }
  78 | 
> 79 |   return enhancer(createStore)(reducer, preloadedState);
     | ^  80 | }
  81 | 
  82 | if (typeof reducer !== 'function') {

Comment: This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41299725/uncaught-error-expected-the-enhancer-to-be-a-function

Comment: Try removing the trailing commas after applyMiddleware(thunk), and the one on the line below it ),